# If $U_1, U_2,.....$ is an infinite collection of open sets , then their intersection is open ? True or false?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $U_1, U_2,.....$ is a infinite collection of open sets , then their intersection is open ? True or false ?

I proved that , If $U_1, U_2,......,U_n$ is a finite collection of open sets , then their intersection is open.

But what happens when the collection is infinite ?

Comment: How did you prove it for the finite case?  Isn't this an axiom of a topology?

Comment: I'm new to topology. If $x$ is an arbitrary element of the intersection , then it should be in all $U_1,U_2,....U_n$ . So whatever I choose in the intersection it belongs to an open set. So there Intersection is open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $U_n =(-1/n, 1/n)$ Clearly the intersection is $\{0\}$ which is not open in the standard topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AdamHughes So is this statement undeterminable? Meaning that we can't say that an infinite collection of open sets is open or closed. Consider an infinite collection of disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the smallest disk having radius of $1$. Then the intersection, which is a open disk of radius 1 is open. So this statement is true in this case?

Comment: @ShiyueLi Maybe on some level, but it's kind of an awkward statement to say "in this case the statement is true," because "the statement" is a general thing, i.e. it's a statement about arbitrary intersections, but "this case" just boils down to "some intersection of open sets is open" which is really obvious, and doesn't really give us any insight at all.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_n=(a,b+\frac{1}{n})$ now $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty =(a,b]$ because b is in all sets $U_n$